# How to upload directories in google drive?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is uploading all the files in google drive but I want to upload all the directories and their subdirectories also. I searched online but didn't find a solution. How to do it?

How to modify this code to upload the directories and subdirectories?

```
def upload_files(self, filename, path):
    folder_id = "18bewyZEHy9VfSLG1N06Ule648luuCPWX"
    media = MediaFileUpload(f"{path}{filename}")

    response = self.service.files().list(
                                    q=f"name='{filename}' and parents='{folder_id}'",
                                    spaces='drive',
                                    fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                    pageToken=None).execute()
    if len(response['files']) == 0:
        file_metadata = {
            'name': filename,
            'parents': [folder_id]
        }
        file = self.service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
        print(f"A new file was created {file.get('id')}")
```

Comment: Can you show an example of data you have and result you would like to achieve? Generally you can recreate your folder structure on Drive, keep the mapping between created folders and those on your file system, and then upload files to their respective folders.

Comment: @zipa So you mean I have to create whole directory tree in google drive and then upload the files belonging to every particular directory. Right?

Comment: That turned out to be the easiest way for me :)